# Custom exception codes and messages in Python 3.4

Tags: python

I'd like to have something like a custom error code/message database and use it when raising exceptions **(in Python 3.4)**. So I did the following:

```
class RecipeError(Exception):

    # Custom error codes
    ERRBADFLAVORMIX = 1
    ERRNOINGREDIENTS = ERRBADFLAVORMIX + 1

    # Custom messages
    ERRMSG = {ERRBADFLAVORMIX: "Bad flavor mix",
              ERRNOINGREDIENTS: "No ingredients to mix"}

raise RecipeError(RecipeError.ERRMSG[RecipeError.ERRBADFLAVORMIX])
```

This works as expected, but the `raise` statement is just monstrous. Sure, I could have stored the values in a more compact way, but what I really want to know is: **Can I just do something like `raise RecipeError(code)` and leave the work of getting the message to RecipeError?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Exception classes are just normal classes, so you can define your own `__init__` that calls `super` appropriately:

```
class RecipeError(BaseException):
    # existing stuff
    def __init__(self, code):
        super().__init__(self, RecipeError.ERRMSG[code])
```

---

You might also want to save the code:

```
class RecipeError(BaseException):
    # existing stuff
    def __init__(self, code):
        msg = RecipeError.ERRMSG[code]
        super().__init__(self, msg)
        self.code, self.msg = code, msg
```

Take a look at the information stored in the standard library's exceptions (which are pretty decent in 3.4, although there are still more changes to come…) to see what kinds of things might be useful to stash.

---

Some side notes:

---

First, it may be better to use subclasses instead of error codes. For example, if someone wants to write code that catches an `ERRBADFLAVORMIX` but not an `ERRNOINGREDIENTS`, they have to do this:

```
try:
    follow_recipe()
except RecipeError as e:
    if e != RecipeError.ERRBADFLAVORMIX:
        raise
    print('Bad flavor, bad!')
```

Or, if you'd used subclasses:

```
try:
    follow_recipe():
except BadFlavorRecipeError as e:
    print('Bad flavor, bad!')
```

That's exactly why Python no longer has a monolithic `OSError` with an `errno` value that you have to switch on, and instead has separate subclasses like `FileNotFoundError`.

---

If you do want to use error codes, you might want to consider using an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), or maybe [one of the fancier enum types on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=enum&submit=search) that make it easier to attach a custom string to each one.

---

You almost never want to inherit from `BaseException`, unless you're specifically trying to make sure your exception doesn't get caught.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I was pretty sure I read that all user-defined exceptions should be derived from `BaseException`, so I just got it wrong.